# Why can't my computer access a specific IP address?

Tags: windows-7, networking

My laptop cannot access a specific IP address and it gets back a timeout when I ping it. This address is accessible from other computers and it is even accessible from another computer using the same wifi router sitting right beside me. A tracert shows asterisks on the first line so I am pretty sure the issue is inside this computer.

I have turned off the firewall and rebooted several times, also shut down a secure tunnel I have been using for a while, but still nothing. I am running Windows 7 and it is current maintenance level. The hosts file has no mention of this site.

Any ideas about what else I can try to make this work?

Comment: Check (disable) security software to test. If the system has a static IP, try changing it.  Verify that your system and the one right beside you are using the same settings for the network, i.e. DNS etc. Try plugging the computer in to use the wired LAN, and re-test.  If this is a Windows system, boot to "safe mode with networking" and re-test.

Comment: Or try one of those utilities that change MAC address of your network card. The change is only temporary, but it allows you to establish whether it is exactly your pc which is being excluded by the machine you are trying to connect to.